# string using conditional operator in c#

Tags: c#

My program output should print whether or not `n` is weird. I tried the below code but when I run the code it is throwing an error like "Can only use array initializer expressions to assign to array types. Try using a new expression instead". Can someone correct the code. Thanks in advance.

These are the rules: 
If N is odd, print Weird
If N is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5, print Not Weird
If N is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20 , print Weird
If N is even and greater than 20, print Not Weird

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Solution
{
  static void Main(String[] args)
  {
      int N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      string s = {(N%2 !=0 ? "Weird" : (N>20 ? "Not Weird" : ((N > 1 && N <6) ? "Not Weird" : "Weird")))};
      Console.writeLine(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the surrounding curly braces.

Comment: Please stop abusing the ternary operator. Focus on making your code readable, not on "smart" one-liners. Even if you use `if` and `else` and make your code easy to read and understand, the compiler is smart enough to compile that and your current one-line into the same executable code.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using an IF statement?

Comment: @NewCallum I could use IF statement instead but I wanted to try with ternary operator.

Comment: Ah okay, I was just curious as I agree with @Someprogrammerdude's point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because, well... you are using an array initialiser as it says.

When you instantiate the string, using `{}` is initialising an array, instead you should be removing that part entirely and using

```
string s = (N%2 !=0 ? "Weird" : (N>20 ? "Not Weird" : ((N > 1 && N <6) ? "Not Weird" : "Weird")));
```

The array initialiser can be used for strings, but only if you are making a `char` array

```
string s = new char[] { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', };
```

Comment: Thanks for your example @Alfie